# g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed Attempt to unlock mutex that was not locked

Tags: ros-melodic, image-transport

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello evryone, i am following this tutorial to create my image subscriber [link text](http://wiki.ros.org/image_transport/Tutorials/SubscribingToImages), using image_transport, however, i meet this problem when i run my subscriber.

> (view:19049): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL
> **: 22:58:39.962: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)'
> failed Attempt to unlock mutex that
> was not locked Aborted (core dumped)
> This is my source code:

```
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <image_transport/image_transport.h>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <cv_bridge/cv_bridge.h>

void imageCallback(const sensor_msgs::ImageConstPtr& msg)
{
  try
      {
    cv::imshow("view", cv_bridge::toCvShare(msg, "bgr8")->image);
    cv::waitKey(30);
  }
  catch (cv_bridge::Exception& e)
  {
    ROS_ERROR("Could not convert from '%s' to 'bgr8'.", msg->encoding.c_str());
  }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  ros::init(argc, argv, "image_listener");
  ros::NodeHandle nh;
  cv::namedWindow("view");
  cv::startWindowThread();
  image_transport::ImageTransport it(nh);
  image_transport::Subscriber sub = it.subscribe("camera/image", 1, imageCallback);
  
  ros::spin();
  cv::waitKey(0);

  cv::destroyWindow("view"); 
}
```

Can you help me to solve this ?
Thanks in advances!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/350608/g_object_unref:-assertion-%27g_is_object-(object)%27-failed-attempt-to-unlock-mutex-that-was-not-locked/) by [N.N.Huy](https://answers.ros.org/users/52680/n.n.huy/) on ROS Answers with karma: 32 on 2020-04-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello i fixed the error. The source code in the website couldn't run.

- Instead of using cv::startWindowThread();, we should use waitKey();
- They forget to add the size parameter in cv::namedWindow("view"); too. => cv::namedWindow("view", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);

---

Originally posted by [N.N.Huy](https://answers.ros.org/users/52680/n.n.huy/) with karma: 32 on 2020-04-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [DJ](https://answers.ros.org/users/54053/dj/) on 2020-06-12**:
Hi, I got the same issue after using the waitkey(). It gave an error stating Assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed. I found that the waitkey(0) causes that error. I am using lidar_camera_calibration ROS for my lidar camera calibration. Would like to get some help. Thanks.

**Comment by [N.N.Huy](https://answers.ros.org/users/52680/n.n.huy/) on 2020-06-22**:
Actually, i am just a beginner and i don't have many experiences in this. You could make a new topic to ask someone with more insight than me could help :) !

**Comment by [iad-AR](https://answers.ros.org/users/69998/iad-ar/) on 2021-02-13**:
@DJ, you replaced cv::startWindowThread() by cv::waitkey(0) ? you should use cv::waitkey(1) instead.

I had the same issue and I found some info on the stackoverflow link bellow. Basically the number between the parenthesis cv::waitkey is a time in millisecond for the program to wait. And if set to 0, then it wait forever (until you press a key).
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5217519/what-does-opencvs-cvwaitkey-function-do